# AQXMLParser and EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION from all over the app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, debugging

A lot of crash reports coming in with this theme. What could be causing this? It's never in the same place twice. I am using AQXMLParser but the crashes are always in some place unconnected to that. I'm not looking for help to diagnose the specific cause of this issue, Seems like some bad memory management in the XML parser delegate (written before I came onboard). So my question: Is there is some class of programming error that would exhibit this behavior? I'd like to learn so I know what to look for in the future.

```
0    <MY APPLICATION> ✭  <SOME RANDOM CLASS THAT HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH XML PARSING>.m line 687
-[<SOME RANDOM  THAT HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH XML PARSING>:] + 687
1
...
libxml2.2.dylib 
__xmlRaiseError + 898
2    libxml2.2.dylib    
xmlFatalErr + 952
3    libxml2.2.dylib    
xmlParseEntityRef + 104
4    libxml2.2.dylib    
xmlParseReference + 270
5    libxml2.2.dylib    
xmlParseTryOrFinish + 1422
6    libxml2.2.dylib    
xmlParseChunk + 212
7    MyApplication   AQXMLParser.m line 1238
-[AQXMLParser stream:handleEvent:] + 1238
8    CoreFoundation 
_signalEventSync + 74
9    CoreFoundation 
_cfstream_shared_signalEventSync + 240
10
...
CoreFoundation  
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
11   CoreFoundation 
__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 212
12   CoreFoundation 
__CFRunLoopRun + 646
13   CoreFoundation 
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
14   CoreFoundation 
CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
15   Foundation 
-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 254
16   MyApplication   AQXMLParser.m line 1115
-[AQXMLParser inputRunRunLoopInMode:] + 1115
17   MyApplication   AQXMLParser.m line 1164
```

Comment: I ran across this issue logged on the AQToolkit GitHub project that points to an error in the code.  https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/issues/18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in an old version of AQXMLParser. Updating to the latest fixed it.